# How to convert a JSON string into JS object?

Tags: javascript, json

I know the method to convert a JS object into a JSON string by using `JSON.stringify(object)` method. How can I encode a string object into JSON?

Comment: You need json format String in order to convert it to JSon Object. and which platform ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't convert a string into JSON. The outermost data type in JSON must be an object or an array.

See [the specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627):

> JSON Grammar
>
> A JSON text is a sequence of tokens.  The set of tokens includes
>   six    structural characters, strings, numbers, and three literal
>   names.
>
> **A JSON text is a serialized object or array.**

You could wrap the string in an object or array and then serialise that:

```
JSON.stringify([myString]);
JSON.stringify({foo: myString});
```

Whatever processed it would have to know that after parsing the JSON it would have to extract the string from it though.

Comment: @Quentin.... suppose i have string like var str ="MyName"  Am i able to use JSON.stringify(str)

Comment: No! A string isn't a `[]` or a `{}`

Comment: SO then need to parse like... JSON.parse({str}) or JSON.parse([str]) ?

Comment: No. You pass a string (containing JSON) to JSON.parse and get a JS object back. If the JSON text starts with an object, you get an object. If it starts with an array, you get an array. You need to put an object or array into **stringify** not **parse**.

Answer (score 4):

Same way:

```
var jsonEncodedString = JSON.stringify(string);
```

or are you asking for the revsere

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify({hello:"world"}),
jsObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Comment: @Tom... it is giving script error as exception thrown not caught... in json2.js at line number 447

Comment: Then what you have probably isn't correctly formatted json, catch and report the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [JSON.parse function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

```
var jsonString = '{"firstname":"Jesper","surname":"Aaberg","phone":["555-0100","555-0120"]}';
var contact = JSON.parse(jsonString);

var fullname = contact.surname + ", " + contact.firstname;
// The value of fullname is "Aaberg, Jesper"
```